# Writing my own 3D Game Engine

Tags: 3d, game-engine

I want to write a simple 3d game engine for **apply**.
I have bought some vital Books like :

- Ultimate 3D game programming by sherrod
- [Advanced 3D Game Programming with DirectX 10.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598220543)
- [Real-Time Rendering, Third Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814240)
- [3D Game Engine Design, Second Edition: A Practical Approach to Real-Time Computer Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122290631)
- [COMPLETE-Effect-HLSL-Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0976613212)
- ShaderX 6
- [Game Engine Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814135)
- [Real-Time Cameras](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123116341)
- Game Programming Gems 6
- Best of Game Programming Gems

I am reading them, but I need a **Road Map**. please give me some advice. thanks.

Comment: Find sometihng you want to do, and do it.

Comment: Write a game you would like to play, and generalize it to an engine later on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend first building at least a small game using an existing engine so that you understand what an engine is from that point of view.  Personally I'd recommend Unity, NeoAxis or UDK.

Then focus on building a game without without such an engine (as others have recommended).  You might want to start by using some existing sub-systems like Ogre3D a slowly replace these with your own.

Then you'll be in position to start thinking about how to make an engine that's suitable for other games.

Jumping straight in to building even a simple engine is a bit like trying to write a novel without having ever read one.  (And actually, novels are pretty simple compared to game engines.)

Of those books, I'd pick Game Engine Architecture and go right through it, rather than flip between different books.  Use the others just for additional points of view, at least for now.

Answer (score 7):

A game engine is what is left over after you make your game data driven. Make the game first like @Oded said, and then start making it more and more data driven. Then make another game, and eventually you will be left with an engine.

Answer (score 3):

I have a tutorial on making a simple 3D game engine on my web site. I walk you through creating the classic 2D game Asteroids using 3D graphic assets that I supply to show the reader how easy it really is.

See [XNA 4 3D game engine tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/xna4tutorsbylance/home).